# Crontab line escape % makes \ in the output

Tags: shell, escaping, cron, solaris

OS solaris.

I am trying to log the system info from uptime command.
For this I schedule a job in crontab which runs every hour.
uptime comes with the output of time but not datetime, so I combine date command with uptime.

I want to have the datetime format yyyymmddHHMM for this I format the date output with format (date +"%Y%m%d%H%M").

It works perfectly if it is not on crontab. 
For crontab **%** causes errors, so I need to escape **%** with **** to make it working. 
So here is my cron job line:

```
0 * * * * bash -c "date +'\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M' | tr '\n' ' ' && uptime" >> /tmp/uptime.log
```

So I expect out to be like that:

> 201703161309   1:09pm  up 52 day(s), 14:45,  2 users,  load
>   average: 0.99, 1.41, 1.45

But what I get is:

> \2017\03\16\13\09   1:09pm  up 52 day(s), 14:45,  2 users,  load
>   average: 0.99, 1.41, 1.45

So how to make it work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You are using bash there is another way to escape the `%`: `$'\045'`. That will look strange but it should work (I have no solaris to test it on)

```
0 * * * * bash -c "date +$'\045'Y$'\045'm$'\045'd$'\045'H$'\045'M | tr '\n' ' ' && uptime" >> /tmp/uptime.log
```